# не могу добавить переменную в базу данных postgresql (psycopg2)выдает ошибку:psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Entry'

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, psycopg2

Не могу решить проблему с добавлением переменной(значением в ней) в базу данных
вот мой код:

```
def jop():
    lbl.configure(text='Вы зарегистрировались',bg='white')
    if not t.get():
        lbl.configure(text='введите логин!')
    elif not p.get():
        lbl.configure(text='введите пароль!')
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr(login)VALUES (%s)", [t])  # correct
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr(password)VALUES (%s)", [p])
    
        connection.commit()
jopa = Tk()  
jopa.title("Регистрация")  
jopa.geometry('400x600')
lbl = Label(jopa, text="Привет",bg='brown1',)  
t=Entry(bg='white')
p=Entry(show='*')
bt=Button(jopa,text='Начать',command=jop,bg='white')
jopa["bg"] = "brown1"



lbl.pack()
t.pack()
p.pack()
bt.pack()



jopa.mainloop()
```

А вот сама ошибка:

> cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr(login)VALUES (%s)", [t])  # correct psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Entry'

Comment: Ну, а зачем Вы пытаетесь какой-то `Entry` добавить в бд?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых строки в таблицы нужно вставлять целиком а не отдельно по полям:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr(login, password) VALUES (%s, %s)", [login, passwd])
```

Во-вторых, в переменных `login` и `passwd` - должны быть значения с типами данных, которые соответствуют типам данных соответствующих столбцов в таблице БД. Судя по названиям - это строки в вашем случае.

---

Ошибка:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Entry'

сообщает вам о том, что `psycopg2` не смог преобразовать объект типа `Entry` к строке для того. чтобы подставить значение для параметра `login`.